# Google Play 0 supported device

Tags: android, google-play

I am trying to upload an update to google play store but after uploading the apk it says 0 supported device.

Some of the similar questions are caused by 3rd party libraries but i don't use any new library.

I am using v7 appcompat support library. I was using v4 previously and it had no problem with Google Play. I don't know if this is the problem but this is the only change i made in terms of external libraries.

Here is my manifest file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.saliherikci.poemnotebook"
    android:versionCode="10"
    android:versionName="2.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="25" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/ic_action_logo"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.saliherikci.poemnotebook.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.saliherikci.poemnotebook.ReadPoemActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_read_poem" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.saliherikci.poemnotebook.SelectedAuthorsPoemsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_selected_authors_poems"
            android:parentActivityName="com.saliherikci.poemnotebook.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.saliherikci.poemnotebook.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.saliherikci.poemnotebook.FavouritesActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_favourites"
            android:parentActivityName="com.saliherikci.poemnotebook.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.saliherikci.poemnotebook.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I wonder what might be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same thing last night and read the most recent articles on this and I guess there is a recent Google bug causing the supported devices to always show up as 0 until it's actually rolled out to production.

I took a chance and released the update and sure enough all the supported devices were there in production. So if you haven't changed anything in the Manifest from the last release you're probably safe to do so as well. (Also I don't see anything in the posted Manifest that would cause any issues)

Comment: Yes it was a bug from Google. I uploaded the app everything is fine. People are able to download it.